# The same number of characters in each line of UITextView?

Tags: iphone, ipad, fonts, ios, uitextview

Hi I'm developing a simple writing program using `UITextView` to study Cocoa programming.
In `UITextView`, each line has different number of characters.
I tried to change fonts of `UITextView`, but the width of each character seems to vary. For example, l and L has different width.

Is there anyway to keep the same number of characters in each line of `UITextView` like emacs or just like this editing box of stackoverflow?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

easiest way is to use a monospaced font like Courier New

Comment: +1, provided you handwave the distinction between "characters"/glyphs/code points, and let's not get into control characters (a tab probably shouldn't be the same width as a space!)

Comment: @tc. Yep, although it is possible to have make each glyph the same size too using CTRunDelegate and CoreText (not recommended)